# How to use Accessibility Different Font Size for our Application?

Tags: ios, uifont, uiaccessibility

I am implementing a functionality of changing font size of complete App.

there will be three mode -- 1. Small 2. Medium 3.Large

by clicking on small, app font will be reduced 20 %

by clicking on Large, app font will be increased by 20%

and by clicking on Middle,app font will remain same .

I implemented this functionality successfully .

But my question is Can i take Accessibility Font Size set by the user in their device settings.

Because i read somewhere that Apple used to reject apps in which there is something common with their settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't look at accessibility settings on iOS. However, with the introduction of iOS 7, you can support Dynamic Type, which allows you to set any font to the system font in the size defined by the user, simply by calling `+preferredFontWithTextStyle:`.

Comment: so i can implement this functionality without any problem na .